# currentUser is undefined is displayed undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use react with redux and I have this problem that results in an infinite loop between login and profile. And when I remove the condition `if(!cuurentUser)` in  profile for debugging it says that `curentUser` is undefined.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Profile = () => {
  const { currentUser }= useSelector((state) => state.auth);

 if (!currentUser) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <header className="jumbotron">
        <h3>
          <strong>{currentUser.username}</strong> Profile
        </h3>
      </header>
      <p>
        <strong>Token:</strong> {currentUser.accessToken.substring(0, 20)} ...{" "}
        {currentUser.accessToken.substr(currentUser.accessToken.length - 20)}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Id:</strong> {currentUser.id}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Email:</strong> {currentUser.email}
      </p>
      <strong>Authorities:</strong>
      <ul>
        {currentUser.roles &&
          currentUser.roles.map((role, index) => <li key={index}>{role}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: in your /login it redirects back to Profile right? You need to share your login codes. You mosslike have a useEffect that's causing the loop.

Comment: So build logic that if currentUser is not defined (after successful login process) redirect to an error page. This is a start for production. Second, did you try to simulate the login process and see for yourself the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component that redirects to your `Profile` component has a logic of redirecting when the user logged in, most likely you are doing it with some `useEffect` hook. Also, that redirecting component needs to populate your Redux store correctly so then when you redirect to `Profile` component your `currentUser` is available in the store otherwise it will always render the `Redirect`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I fixed the problem by adding this:

```js
const  {user: currentUser}  = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```